# Determine if part of two arrays equal in java

Tags: java

I have two char arrays of different length, 
and I want to compare whether the first few chars in both arrays are the same.
e.g.

```
char[] pngheader = new char[] { 137, 80, 78, 71 }; // PNG
char[] fileheader = new char[] { 137, 80, 78, 71 , xxx, xxx};
```

I am wondering whether if I could do this using some elegant way like Arrays.equals()?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the index of the chars?

Comment: few character means? even 0 comes into this category :-)

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. But for the current case if you wanted an "elegant" way .. this is what I could come up with :
Arrays.equals(pngheader,Arrays.copyOf(fileheader, pngheader.length));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Arrays` class provides some helpful methods for your situation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] pngheader = new char[] { 137, 80, 78, 71 }; // PNG
    char[] fileheader = new char[] { 137, 80, 78, 71 , 1, 2}; 
    char[] fileheader2 = new char[] { 131, 80, 78, 71 , 1, 2}; 

    boolean equals = Arrays.equals(Arrays.copyOf(pngheader, 4),
                                        Arrays.copyOf(fileheader, 4));
    System.out.println(equals); //prints true

    boolean equals2 = Arrays.equals(Arrays.copyOf(pngheader, 4),
                                       Arrays.copyOf(fileheader2, 4));
    System.out.println(equals2); //prints false
}
```

This could also be made more reusable by creating a method.

```
    public static boolean arraysEquals(char[] arr1, char[] arr2, int length){
        return Arrays.equals(Arrays.copyOf(arr1, length -1), 
                        Arrays.copyOf(arr2, length -1));
    }

    //Usage

    arraysEquals(pngheader, fileheader, 4);
    arraysEquals(pngheader, fileheader2, 4);
```

Comment: in this case, you don't need `Arrays.copyOf(pngheader, 4)`, `pngheader` will suffice.

Comment: @jlordo That is just incase the OP doesn't want to compare the entire first array to the second.  This would allow the first array to have some garbage after the indexes we are concerned with.

Answer (score 1):

This will work with char arrays

```
    char[] pngheader = new char[] { 137, 80, 78, 71 }; // PNG
    char[] fileheader = new char[] { 137, 80, 78, 71 , 1, 1}; 
    boolean res = new String(fileheader).startsWith(new String(pngheader));
    System.out.println(res);
```